# when I meet a friend who is a foreigner and come to my country. I ask him: "who have u come with?"

Tags: sentence-construction

when I meet a friend who is a foreigner and come to my country.
I wanna ask him "who have u come with?"
does this sound natural?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*When a friend who is a foreigner comes to my country, and I meet him, I ask him: "Who have you come with?" Does this sound natural?*

The short answer is that an American would understand very well what you're asking him. I would say the average American English speaker would tend to say, "Who have you come with," or "Who did you come with?"

However, using more formal English would require you to say or write, "With whom did you come?" "With" is a preposition and its object is "whom."

I would guess that many (most?) native American English speakers don't know or follow the rules regarding "who" and "whom."

Here's the results of a search for information on using [who and whom](https://www.bing.com/search?q=who%20whom&form=EDNTHB&mkt=en-us&httpsmsn=1&plvar=0&refig=e03f31a4b9274e65df1ab3600ca8eab2&sp=1&qs=HS&sc=8-0&cvid=e03f31a4b9274e65df1ab3600ca8eab2&cc=US&setlang=en-US).

If you were to read up on this topic, I think you would find that there is a debate about whether or not it is even necessary to distinguish between "who
and "whom" for most situations.

You will find sites on that list of search results that will help you learn the use of these words.